# Free code coverage tools

Tags: windows, linux, code-coverage, native

Are there any free code coverage tools for native (not managed) code?
For either Windows or Linux platforms?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) from the GNU tools.

Answer (score 3):

[EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) is a free Java code coverage tool, and there's [NCover](http://ncover.sourceforge.net/) for .NET

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with valgrind:

http://benjamin-meyer.blogspot.com/2007/12/valgrind-callgrind-tools-part-3-code.html